# DidReceiveRemoteNotification with Task.Run?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I need to call awaitable methods from within DidReceiveRemoteNotification override in my AppDelegate class.

I understand there is a time limit for this override to complete its work under iOS.

Is it ok to call Task.Run or even Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunning) inside the DidReceiveRemoteNotification override method?

Are there any alternatives for if I want to do background work when receiving notification?

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to call `Task.Run()` inside the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` like below. Also, don't forget to enable background modes (Background fetch and Remote notifications) in the `Info.plist` file.

```
[Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")]
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
  if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
  {
           
       Task.Run(async () =>
       {
           //await callMyForegroundMethod();
       }); 
   }
}
```